# How do you remove the status line from the MiniBufExplorer window

Tags: vim, statusline

I'm using Vim with MiniBufExplorer.

How do you hide the statusline for the MBE window? I've tried every permutation of setting laststatus (0,1,2) but the best I get is the status line disappearing on the bottom of the gVim window but remaining near the top just under the MiniBufExplorer window.

I want the statusline only to exist near the bottom of the gVim window.

Any help?
THANKS!

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do that. But if the problem is wasted screen space, I suggest you to try the buftabs plugin (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1664), it uses the statusline to show you the open buffers. I used MBE for a long time but switched recently, and I'm very satisfied.

Comment: +1 for buftabs. It does exactly what you asked for. I myself have moved from MiniBufExplorer to buftabs for exactly the same reason.

Comment: Instead of moving to another plugin in order to save screen space as suggested by @MagnunLeno, one could also add some nice mappings to the `~/.vimrc` that allow for showing all open buffers (based on `:ls`) only when one wants to open another buffer with `nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>`. For splits checkout the full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571494/open-a-buffer-as-a-vertical-split-in-vim/61342451#61342451).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot eliminate the status line from the `MiniBufExplorer` window in a horizontal split.

The first line of the `:help status-line` entry reads:

> A status line will be used to separate windows.

You might not realize that this definitively answers your question unless you know that Vim's help files are unusually comprehensive and precise. If you have multiple windows, they *will* be separated by a status line. The `laststatus` option only affects whether that status line also appears a) in the bottom-most window or b) when you have only a single window.

zefei has a [nice fork](https://github.com/zefei/buftabs) of the `buftabs` plugin already mentioned in the comments. There are various other plugins like [`FuzzyFinder`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/FuzzyFinder) and [`ctrlp`](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/) that offer alternative space-saving buffer listing and switching solutions.

See also: [An alternative to minibufexplorer (vim)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865132/an-alternative-to-minibufexplorer-vim?rq=1)