# Open a buffer as a vertical split in Vim

Tags: vim

If you are editing a file in Vim and then you need to open an existing buffer (e.g., from your buffer list: `:buffers`), how can you open it in a vertical split?

I know that you already can open it with a *normal* split like:

```
:sbuffer N
```

Where `N` is the buffer number you want. However, the above opens that `N` buffer horizontally, not vertically.

I'm also aware that you can change the window placement after opening and have a *vertical split* like so:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>

Which will vertically split the window to the right or the left.

It seems to me that if there is a `sbuffer` there should be a `vsbuffer`, but that doesn't exist (not that I am aware of).

Also, please note that I am not looking for a plugin to solve this question. I know about a wealth of plugins that will allow you to do this.

I am sure I might be missing something that is already there.

I have created a simple *function* with a *mapping* if someone else stumbles across this issue and do not want to install a plugin:

Function:

```
" Vertical Split Buffer Function
function VerticalSplitBuffer(buffer)
    execute "vert belowright sb" a:buffer
endfunction
```

Mapping:

```
" Vertical Split Buffer Mapping
command -nargs=1 Vbuffer call VerticalSplitBuffer(<f-args>)
```

This accomplishes the task of opening a buffer in a right split, so for buffer 1, you would call it like:

```
:Vbuffer 1
```

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Try:

```
:vert sb N
```

which will open a left vertical split (by default, unless you have modified some options).

To open a split to the right, on the other hand:

```
:vert belowright sb N
```

Comment: doesn't it seem rather odd to not have ``vsbuffer N`` ? Annoying. Your answer nails it. Thanks!

Comment: I always feel like there should be a `vsbuffer` too, and I also often forget `Ctrl-w T` to open a buffer in a new tab (or I want to do that with a buffer that's not currently active or visible). So as an alternative, you can use a bar for either of these cases, which I find easier to remember than @Jeet's valid answer: `:vsp | b N` and `:tabe | b N`.

Comment: I like that this command allows `N` to be autocompleted (which doesn't seem possible with the command in the other answer). Both upvoted, nevertheless.

Answer (score 134):

`:vsp | b1`

1 being some buffer number. Use `buffers` to list all buffers.

Here's some additional info on splits, if you're interested. 
[Link](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/vim-splits-a-guide-to-doing-exactly-what-you-want/)

Comment: You could also use `:ls`, which seems to be a shortcut for `:buffers`.

Comment: you can also do `:vsp | b <buffer name>`

Comment: @KennyBambridge even better - you only have to type part of the buffer name (case sensitive) and then hit tab to cycle through the filtered list

Comment: Bear in mind that although the [Link](https://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/vim-splits-a-guide-to-doing-exactly-what-you-want/) provided by @Jerinaw is good the terminology on that page is seriously misleading so you'll need to read the comments on that page as well to clarify.

Answer (score 11):

The answer to the OP that I found most useful is embedded deep in Jerinaw's answer and a comment on it, and in Wolfson's answer. But I felt it might be brought out more. (Nor have those been voted most highly, even though they seemed to me the ones that answered OP best.)

The answer to the question, Why is there not `:vsbuffer`, is that there is. It's called `:vsplit` and does the trick either as

`:vsplit NameOfBuffer`

OR

`:vsplit #NumberOfBuffer`.

(In this second use, take care to note that the hash # is significant. If you want to get to buffer number 3, you need to say `:vsplit #3`, not just `:vsplit 3` which will instead create a new file named "3".)

Again, this answer is embedded above, it's just not brought out clearly enough for the quick scanner, IMV.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It makes a new file with the number/name.

Comment: When using NumberOfBuffer, say it's 3, did you put in `:vsplit #3`? Without the hash, `:vsplit 3` will indeed make a new file with name `3`? (That is, the hash is required.)

Answer (score 7):

You can ease your pain by adding the following to your .vimrc

```
cabbrev vb vert sb
```

Now you can use it in the following way.

```
:vb <buffer>
```

Comment: this is nice, the extended version offers also buffers name autocompletion!
I didn't know cabbrev too, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also combine `:ls` that lists your current buffers and the commands to open the desired buffer in either

1. current window: `:b <N/bufname>`
2. vertical split: `:vsp | b <N/bufname>`
3. horizontal split: `:sp | b <N/bufname>`

For this, I've added the following mappings to my `~/.vimrc` (order of mappings represents the above list of desired windows)

```
 nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>
 nnoremap <leader>v :ls<cr>:vsp<space>\|<space>b<space>
 nnoremap <leader>s :ls<cr>:sp<space>\|<space>b<space>
```

Based on this, you can see the buffer list as soon as you hit

1. `<leader>b`
2. `<leader>v`
3. `<leader>s`

and then just enter the desired buffer number `N`. This will then open the buffer in the desired window. You can of course still use a part of the buffer name `bufname` as well.

I mapped the `<leader>` to `,` based on

```
let mapleader = ","
```

For some people (e.g. me) this could even replace plugins like MiniBufExpl and thus save space on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Neovim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Neovim), like this:

```
autocmd FileType python nmap <F5> :rightbelow vertical split <bar> :term python %<cr>
```