# An alternative to minibufexplorer (vim)?

Tags: vim, minibufexplorer

**minibufexplorer** is a persistent buffer manager for vim that lives in its own window.  It shows all the buffers you have open, with color indicators as to which are currently visible in windows and which have unsaved changes.

It's a great plugin which I've been hooked on forever.  And without the persistent buffer display I find that I now feel lost.

The problem is, minibufexpl tends to get in the way of other window controls.  As it is a normal vim window, it behaves like one, causing issues if you wanted to say, rotate your other working windows.  Minibufexplorer's window would rotate as well, which is obviously less than desirable.

What I really need is a plugin that persistently displays the open buffers, but doesn't behave like a window.  I don't need file navigation or anything as I use other means for that.  Perhaps even something like an extended status bar that was capable of displaying information on buffers like minibufexpl does?

Comment: I have seen that a SO user, Randy Morris, has started working on persistent buffer list in status line. See https://github.com/rson/vim-bufstat but I don't know if it is working. It is a good idea though.

Comment: looks promising.  I'll definitely check this out later.

Comment: @Xavier T.: Thanks for the plug :)
@numbers: My plugin is based off the same idea as buftabs.vim which is in an answer below.  It's meant to be very simple but it has not been tested very thoroughly.  If you do try it, I'd appreciate any feedback on github.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's [a new fork of minibufexpl.vim on GitHub](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim) which aims to solve some of these problems. One of its new features is "Prevents resizing of MBE buffer by window resizing commands" and it is immune to commands such as <kbd>C-W</kbd><kbd>C-R</kbd> (rotate windows).

https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim

Comment: This is awesome.  I've been "off" minibufexplorer for most the year now.  As of tomorrow, I'll probably be hooked again.  Thanks for the find!

Comment: No problem! Just found it today.

Answer (score 17):

While this is not an exact answer to your question, I think you could find it useful.

[FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) plugin provides good visual representation of your open buffers,
and also offers **great** way to jump between them - fuzzy match.

Its list of buffers is not "persistent" meaning it's only shown on
demand, but I consider this an advantage: firstly the buffers list doesn't eat
up precious screen estate, and secondly with fuzzy match I don't feel a
need to see it at all.

Consider the below screenshot: in order to switch to `ext_gcd.py` I just need to press
`,bg` : `,b` invokes buffers list and `g` fuzzy-matches the only buffer
whose name contains letter *g*.

[image]

P.S: it works with files too. My mappings are as follows:

```
map <leader>f :FufFileWithCurrentBufferDir **/<C-M> 
map <leader>b :FufBuffer<C-M>
```

`,f` in this case recursively fuzzy-matches files starting from a directory where current buffer is placed.

Comment: +1 on this, I love fuzzyfinder and use it constantly for opening files and jumping between buffers.  But yeah, my issue isn't navigation, it's the persistent display of buffers.  I know it's just because I'm so used to it and I'd probably get over it within a week of cutting out minibufexplorer.  I just hope to find a nice solution before it comes to that.

Comment: If you like the idea of this, but don't quite like fuzzyfinder's implementation, [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) is a similar plugin.

Answer (score 14):

Old thread, but for anyone else searching checkout the [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) plugin. It's very popular and has great compatibility with other plugins.

Use the g:airline#extensions#bufferline#enabled option to get what your looking for.

Comment: Just switched myself just now. Might also be interested inlet g:airline#extensions#tabline#buffer_nr_show

Answer (score 9):

I really enjoy [buftabs.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1664) because it keeps the information about which buffers I have open in the status line, which disappear when I need to type there in a nice clear manner. I find this quite preferable to *minibufexplorer* because my cursor never accidentally ends up in a read-only scratch buffer which takes up more space than necessary. It also does some magic-mapping of `:bnext` and `:blast` to allow hopping between buffers for a rather more "familiar" feeling.

[image]

Comment: Giving this a shot.  Seems good.  If only it could color highlight.

Comment: Pretty good in concept.  Problem for me is that I think I have other plugins vying for that space (supertab for one) and when I really need the tabs to be there I look down to find that they haven't redrawn.  Will have to look into how to fix the issue when I get some more time... busy week.

Comment: Probably could use some [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/) love.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim), a plugin written in pure Vimscript and highly [configurable](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt).

`:CtrlPBuffer` open a window with the list of open buffers

you can begin to type, it is a fuzzy finder.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Tagma Buffer Manager](https://github.com/LStinson/TagmaBufMgr). I am not using it yet, but someday I will give it a try, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Powerline's tabline`!

I tried many plugins but they tend to take up the command line or the status line, or won't show up the whole tabs when there're too many of them.

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FF62016923F0F472%212148) is a screen shot (the top bar is the `tabline`!):

You need to add `set showtabline=2` in .vimrc after install Powerline.

And if you want to go to the 8th buffer, `:b 8` will jump to it!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your screenshot looks suspiciously like [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline).  Are you sure that functionality isn't coming from a plugin?  Isn't the `tabline` option typically for tabs, not buffers?

Comment: It is actually `Powerline` but you're right, it is coming from a plug-in, but it still needs to be configured. Thanks for pointing that out.